# What is the difference between staged limitting and normal limitting?

Tags: mastering, terminology, master

i was checking some mastering document and i saw something about staged limitting. What is its benefit ? Is that better than normal limitting techniques ?

Comment: Do you have a link to the mastering document that you are referring to?

Comment: i saw a tip about limitting it was like that:

Three limitters with a gain reduction of 1db might sound more natural than a single 3db limitting stage

Comment: It may well sound more natural, as you can soften your thresholds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Compressor by FMR audio, called RNC , this compressor has a "Super-Nice" Mode , while this is not a 100% limiter, a limiter is just a very fast compressor (in simple terms).

So , i have no exact reference to something called "Staged limiting" , but when we use the word "Staged" in audio we mean a process that's happening step by step , for example gain staging.

So what RNC does is routing 3 compressors to minimize the compression artifacts and smooth out the result.

I quote from the RNC quickstart Guide:

*Super-Nice  Operation  —
This  proprietary  mode  layers  three  compressors
together to minimize compression artifacts while still providing control over the
signal. 
This is not an “auto” mode
...all parameter knobs still work to give YOU con-
trol over the signal. The intended purpose of this mode is gentle compression of
an entire mix (i.e., program compression) and compression of sound sources that
must be very gently compressed, yet controlled*

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Flux's multi-stage limiter called Elixir:
http://www.fluxhome.com/products/plug_ins/elixir-v3

"For truly delicate and fine processing tasks (mastering etc.) Elixir v3 presents a new innovative concept called Stages, providing the option to set the algorithm to perform the limiting processing in multi-stages, in order to achieve even more precise and natural sounding results.

Example: If the threshold is set to -3 dB and the ‘Stages’ parameter set to 3, the first stage will limit at -1dB, the second stage will limit at -2dB and the third will limit at -3dB, with analyzing performed in each of the three stages."